# How can I configure /etc/hosts with ansible orchestration

Tags: ansible

The application needs the following hosts:

```
[foo-servers]
foo-server ansible_ssh_host=192.168.50.2 

[bar-servers]
bar-server ansible_ssh_host=192.168.50.3 

[mysql-servers]
mysql-server ansible_ssh_host=192.168.50.4 

[mongodb-servers]
mongodb-server ansible_ssh_host=192.168.50.5
```

I need to configure hosts on foo server and bar server as they need to access mysql and mongodb. To achieve this, I introduce a role named hosts:

```
# roles/hosts/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: change hosts
template: src=hosts.j2 dest=/etc/hosts

# roles/hosts/templates/hosts.j2
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

{% for item in hostvars %}
{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_ssh_host'] }} {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is when I run

```
ansible-playbook foo.yml
```

The /etc/hosts on the target only contains the ip and hostname of the current host, foo-server in this case.

My question is:

How can I get all hosts in the inventory when I run playbook against only one of them?

Or could you suggest some alternatives as I get the wrong idea at the first place.

The alternatives come to my mind are:

Make hosts configuration an individual playbook against all hosts like

```
---
- name: Configuring hosts
  hosts: all
  user: root

  roles:
    - hosts
```

The drawback is I need to run this playbook before others and this seems not a right way to use roles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed this is weird, since even the docs say :

> If, at this point, you haven’t talked to that host yet in any play in
> the playbook or set of playbooks, you can get at the variables, but
> you will not be able to see the facts.

I understand from this that you might not get gathered facts if host hasn't been "queried" yet, but you still should see variables defined in inventory (and group/host vars).
May be you should push that to the mailing list.

In the mean time, you can solve your problem using `groups['all']` to loop over your hosts instead :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

{% for item in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_ssh_host'] }} {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

{% for host in groups['all'] %}

{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ host  }}   {{ hostvars[host].ansible_fqdn }}

{% endfor  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is my solution for anyone who is interested.

### hosts/dev.ini

```
[controller]
controller1 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.10
controller2 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.11
controller3 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.12

[compute]
compute1 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.13
compute2 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.14
compute3 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.15

[block]
block1 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.16
block2 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.17

[haproxy]
haproxy1 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.18

[nginx]
nginx1 ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.19

[deployment]
deployment ansible_ssh_host=10.11.11.20

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

### tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Update /etc/hosts
  become: true
  blockinfile:
      path: /etc/hosts
      create: yes
      block: |
        127.0.0.1 localhost

        # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
        ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
        fe00::0 ip6-localnet
        ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
        ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
        ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
        ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

        {% for item in ansible_play_batch %}
        {{ hostvars[item].ansible_ssh_host }}   {{ item }}    
        {% endfor %}
```

Notes:

- python 3.7.5 ansible 2.9.0
- I decided to go with blockinfile instead of using templates because hostvars context was not getting updated inside the template. Plus I was in a hurry :-).

Answer (score 0):

i am using vagrant to provision MV, but i was not working the hostmanager plugin, so in ansible helped this solution.

```
        - name: hosts to all hosts
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    block: |
      {% for host in groups['all'] %}
      {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['hostname'] }} {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['enp0s8']['ipv4']['address'] }}
      {% endfor %}
    state: present
```

cat /etc/hosts
"
-# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
K8SETCD11 192.168.56.11
K8SETCD12 192.168.56.12
-# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
"